# Custom service returns "401 (Unauthorized : Missing required argument merchant_id)"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a custom service module, but it shows 401.

resource:

```
$resources =  array(
    'get_contacts' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'index' => array(
          'help' => 'Get customers and their contacts',
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'sync_contacts', 'name' => 'resources/sync_contacts.resource'),
          'callback' => '_get_customer_contacts',
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'merchant_id',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => t('Get customers and their contacts by merchant_id.'),
              'source' => array('data' => 'merchant_id'),
              'optional' => FALSE,              
            ),
          ),
          'access callback file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'drupalgap',
            'name' => 'drupalgap.resource',
          ),
          'access callback' => '_sync_contacts_access',
          'access arguments' => array('view'),
          'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Service function:

```
function sync_contacts_get_customers_list(options) {
  try { 
    options.method = 'GET'; 
    options.path = 'get_contacts.json';//'.json' removed and tested also
    options.service = 'sync_contacts';
    options.resource = 'get_contacts';

    Drupal.services.call(options);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log( error);
  }
}
```

Service function call:

```
try {
    var my_args = {
        merchant_id: 1
    };
    sync_contacts_get_customers_list({
      data: JSON.stringify(my_args),
      success: function(result) {           
        drupalgap_alert("SUCCESSSS");
        $("#contactList").append(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));    
      }
    });
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
```

POSTMAN:

[image: POSTMAN Screenshot]
This is how I used the custom service. when I execute it, it shows "401 (Unauthorized : Missing required argument merchant_id)".

How can I fix this issue?

`SOLUTION:` Used Tyler's resource in his answer below and service call modified as below(changed GET to POST and path modified accordingly).

`Note:` To test, in POSTMAN also we have to call with POST and pass the `merchant_id` as `Raw` ie. `{"merchant_id": 1}`

```
function sync_contacts_get_customers_list(options) {    
   try {    
     options.method = 'POST';   
     options.path = 'sync_contacts_resources/get_contacts';
     options.service = 'sync_contacts';
     options.resource = 'get_contacts';

     Drupal.services.call(options);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log( error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check whether your custom service is working with POSTMAN client, in your browser.

Comment: Yes, in POSTMAN also it shows the same error. I will try to fix.

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of postman.. with the error and arguments that you are passing..

Comment: Attached the POSTMAN screenshot

Comment: Try to pass values in raw with {"merchant_id":"1"}

Comment: I'm using GET method, is it possible to pass as 'row' with GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `POST` method in the `sync_contacts_get_customers_list` function:

`options.method = 'POST';`

Without this, you aren't "posting" anything up to Drupal Services, so your resource in Drupal will not be delivered the `merchant_id`.

If you want to use a `GET` request, then I'd recommend using a Views JSON (from [Views datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource)) and a contextual filter(s), otherwise custom resources in Services always use `POST` *AFAIK*, unless you're building a CRUD interface for an Entity (e.g. [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity)).

Also the way you are defining your custom resource in Drupal is incorrect, use `actions` instead:

```
  $resources = array(
    'sync_contacts_resources' => array(
      'actions' => array(
        'get_contacts' => array(
          'help' => 'Get customers and their contacts',
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'sync_contacts', 'name' => 'resources/sync_contacts.resource'),
          'callback' => '_get_customer_contacts',
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'merchant_id',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => t('Get customers and their contacts by merchant_id.'),
              'source' => array('data' => 'merchant_id'),
              'optional' => FALSE,              
            ),
          ),
          'access callback file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'drupalgap',
            'name' => 'drupalgap.resource',
          ),
          'access callback' => '_sync_contacts_access',
          'access arguments' => array('view'),
          'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: My requirement is to get the records based on `merchant_id` that's why I used GET method. In my understanding POST is used to create record. (when I try with POST it shows : 404 (Not found : Could not find the controller.))

Comment: I agree that a strict definition of POST is to create a record, but custom service resources are not very strict, and you can accomplish some unconventional, but functional, things. I've updated my answer to reflect the correct use of `actions` instead of `operations` when declaring your custom service resource in Drupal.

Comment: Tyler, Thank you for your time! its working!. I will update my ticket also with the changes I have done.